# Can I make csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin not unique?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4, doctrine and the csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin for sorting. But I only need it in subform, so that the uniqueness of the position is disturbing. Is there by any chance a posibility to make it not unique?

I am already thinking of doing it manually but if I can avoid to invent the wheel a second time, I am more than thankful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the source, I think it's possible to disable the `unique` option.

In your `schema.yml`:

```
MyModel:
  columns:
    ...
  actAs:
    Sortable:
      unique: false
```

You could also use the `uniqueBy` option to set the fieldname which references the parent. It will then create an unique index by both `position` and the field. Something like this:

```
MyModel:
  columns:
    parent_id: ~
  actAs:
    Sortable:
      uniqueBy: parent_id
```